# How does recovering with injuries or trauma work?

Tags: happiest-apocalypse-on-earth

In our game (I'm a player) a character has trauma. This led to a confusion of the part of the rules that says

> Once injured or traumatized, the character can no longer recover

Our initial interpretation of it was that injury/trauma means that the harm/shock can't be cured, but now we're not sure.

Does "recover" refer only to the trauma or does it include the shock?

Comment: As it's a new tag with limited information can you provide a link to the game's Web site, point of sale, or Wiki entry so casual readers have some context?

Comment: @HeyICanChan done. :)

Comment: That tag description makes the concept sound *awesome.* Thank you for asking this question and introducing me to the game. Feel free to delete these comments whenever. (Not a fan of *Apocalypse World* and its hacks, but the setting…!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HAOE designer here! The strict meaning of the rule is that an injury or trauma count as a permanent harm or shock (respectively). That effectively means you are down to a capacity of 2 harm and/or shock if you have one injury or trauma. If it happens again, you are down to 1, until the character is dead or their mind is broken. Characters can come back from being dead or insane, but there are separate rules for that.

Although it isn't stipulated, the Narrator could reasonably allow a character to heal an injury or trauma with long-term professional care (though the game doesn't expect that to happen because no such facility exists in Mouse Park).

Additionally, characters can always use the move "Wish Upon a Star" to completely recover no matter how much trauma is sustained (which of course has its own challenges).

As a final note, harm and shock are tracked separately (eg one can have trauma without being injured).

Will be sure to take a closer look at how this explained in the upcoming 1.5 version update coming in the next couple months.

Comment: Hi Christopher, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Nice to have a designer answering questions about their game. For future reference you may like to read [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6507/48759) that applies to your situation, but this answer is fine so you don't need to take any action. Thanks for contributing and good luck with the next release!